# AppCenter Build: error CS0103: The name 'Android' does not exist in the current context

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

I have a problem with the AppCenter Build service.
I am building `Xamarin.Forms` project and it this shows error on all line, Where I used Android namespace.

`error CS0103: The name 'Android' does not exist in the current context`

I use full path for classes, not "using"
I use a command like this `Android.OS.Enveironment . . . .` and this causes that errors.

Any Solution?

Comment: Hi, any solution for this?

Comment: See how I resolved my issue below, don't know if it is the same for you, it depends on what kind of project you are including `Mono.Android` in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was because I was referencing `Mono.Android` in a `.Net Standard` project, which works well, but is not recognised as an Android project by AppCenter (bug?) hence AppCenter does not know it has to use its own `Mono.Android` lib to build the project(s).

I resolved this by choosing **Android Library** as template for my projects that need `Mono.Android`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this with the following steps :

1. Remove projectname.dependencies.assemblies.Mono.Android
2. Re-add projectname.dependencies.assemblies.Mono.Android
   I re-added Mono.android v10.0
   And no more this : The name 'Android' does not exist in the current context